# Does prestashop enforce filesize limits outside of the php.ini?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I've installed a fresh version of Prestashop 1.7.3.4 and tried to install a module. If I upload it, I get this error message:

```
Oops... Upload failed.
What happened?
File is too big (219.03MiB). Max filesize: 50MiB.
```

However, in the Information tab of the very same installation, it reads:

```
Server information
Server information Linux #156-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 08:53:28 UTC 2018 x86_64
Server software version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
PHP version: 7.1.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Memory limit: 128M
Max execution time: 30
Upload Max File size: 300M
```

Thus, the chances in my php.ini are registered by prestashop. Every other topic on this subject that I could find, redirected towards changing the php.ini file. Which I have done to begin with.

Comment: BTW, which is this module that weights 220Mb?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Please search variable `$MaxSizeUpload` at file `admin/filemanager/config/config.php`.

Option 2:
Open `Advanced Parameters -> Administration` and check `Upload Quota` fields

Comment: The variable `$MaxSizeUpload` was defined with `100M` in `config.php`. I've increased it to `300M`, cleared cookies and restarted apache. I'm still getting the `50M` error message.